# Find min date in a range with conditions in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to find the first StayStart by customer within the same LegalStart/LegalEnd dates that are >= 8 days (LOS) and are Type 1 only.  Consecutive stays of Type 1 that are less than 8 days count if they add up to 8 days and there isn’t another Type interrupting them.  In that case I need the earliest of the consecutive stays. And that is what I can't figure out how to approach. Adding up consecutive stays that are under 8 but add up to 8. I’d love to post something I’ve tried, but I have gotten nowhere.
This is my table:

```
cust# LegalStart    StayStart   StayEnd    LegalEnd       Type  LOS(days) 
1000    5/3/2013    2/1/2016    2/5/2016    11/18/2016        1       4
1000    5/3/2013    2/5/2016    2/8/2016    11/18/2016        1       3
1000    5/3/2013    2/8/2016    2/11/2016   11/18/2016        2       3
1000    5/3/2013    2/11/2016   2/28/2016   11/18/2016        1      17
1000    3/2/2016    3/2/2016    3/5/2016    11/18/2016        1       4
1000    3/2/2016    3/5/2016    3/7/2016    11/18/2016        1       2
1000    3/2/2016    3/7/2016    3/11/2016   11/18/2016        1       4
1000    3/2/2016    3/12/2016   3/22/2016   11/18/2016        1      10
2000    3/1/2011    12/1/2015   12/3/2015   1/8/2016          1       2
2000    3/1/2011    12/3/2015   12/5/2015   1/8/2016          1       2
2000    3/1/2011    12/5/2015   12/6/2015   1/8/2016          1       1
2000    3/1/2011    12/6/2015   12/18/2015  1/8/2016          1      12
```

Expected Results

```
cust#   LegalStart  StayStart   StayEnd     LegalEnd     Type   LOS(days)
1000    5/3/2013    2/11/2016   2/28/2016   11/18/2016     1      17
1000    3/2/2016    3/2/2016    3/5/2016    11/18/2016     1       4
2000    3/1/2011    12/1/2015   12/3/2015   1/8/2016       1       2
```

My first result is the one with the 17 LOS because the rows for that customer previous to it do add up to 10 days HOWEVER, one of those stays is a Type 2 so it doesn’t count.  The other 2 stays add up to 7 days so they don’t count.  Therefore, the StayStart of 2/11/16 with an LOS of 17 is the min date that meets my criteria.
The second result for that same cust# is during the next Legal Date timeframe and that stay of 4 days plus the next 2 stays of 2 days and 4 days are all Type 1 so they add up to more than or = 8 days. Therefore the StayStart date of 3/2/16 is the min date that meets my criteria.
The 3rd result line is of the next customer and that is correct because all 4 rows for that customer are Type 1 and add up to >= 8 days. Therefore, the StayStart of 12/1/15 is the min date that meets my criteria.
Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (mysql, sql server, postgresql, oracle...)? And are these dates stored as a date type, or something else?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: should be max not min however you can use rank or row_number window functions for sql-server and maybe some types

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had added at the top that I am using SQL server.  and why would it be max when I have to find the first date....the oldest, or earliest, etc.?

Comment: No I haven't tried anything b/c I had this code written to just find the min date that was <= 8....and then they threw this curveball at me that smaller, consecutive stays added up to 8 or more count.

Comment: and the dates are datetime type

Comment: I dont understand the logic. Can you elaborate how you go from your data to your expected output?

Comment: I edited my original post with the results logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that should work with MS SQL Server versions that support analytic functions.

```
select distinct custNum, legalStart, stayStart, stayEnd, legalEnd, type, losDays
from (
  select
    custNum, legalStart, legalEnd, type,
    first_value(stayStart) over (partition by gg order by stayStart) as stayStart,
    first_value(stayEnd) over (partition by gg order by stayEnd) as stayEnd,
    first_value(losDays) over (partition by gg order by stayEnd) as losDays,
    sum(losDays) over (partition by gg order by stayStart) as accLosDays
  from (
    select
      custNum, legalStart, legalEnd, stayStart, stayEnd, type, losDays,
      case when g is not null
        then g
        else min(g) over (
          partition by custNum, legalStart, legalEnd
          rows between current row and unbounded following)
        end as gg
    from (
      select 
        custNum, legalStart, legalEnd, stayStart, stayEnd, type,
        datediff(day,stayStart,stayEnd) as losDays,
        case
          when lead(type, 1, -1)
            over (partition by custNum, legalStart, legalEnd order by stayStart) != type 
          then row_number() over ()
          else null end as g
      from
        theTable
      order by
        custNum,
        legalStart,
        legalEnd,
        stayStart,
        type
    ) z
  ) zz
  where
    type=1
) zzz
where
  accLosDays >= 8;
```

To understand how it works, I suggest running each select statement starting with the innermost one and working outward:

```
select 
  custNum, legalStart, legalEnd, stayStart, stayEnd, type,
  datediff(day,stayStart,stayEnd) as losDays,
  case
    when lead(type, 1, -1)
      over (partition by custNum, legalStart, legalEnd order by stayStart) != type 
    then row_number() over ()
    else null end as g
from
  theTable
order by
  custNum,
  legalStart,
  legalEnd,
  stayStart,
  type
```

This query groups the table rows into partitions by customer and legal date range. The last row of every group (determined either by the end of the partition or a change in the value of the type column) triggers the current overall row number to be assigned to the output column named g, and g is left null otherwise.

The next query "up" takes these rows with the values of g set, and emits a new column gg which fills in null values of g with the correct value for its group:

```
select
  custNum, legalStart, legalEnd, stayStart, stayEnd, type, losDays,
  case
    when g is not null
    then g
    else min(g) over (
      partition by custNum, legalStart, legalEnd
      rows between current row and unbounded following
    ) end as gg
from
  <<<<inner query>>>>
```

Finally, the first stayStart, stayEnd and losDays values are pulled out for the result, which is filtered by type and the total number of days per group:

```
select distinct
  custNum, legalStart, stayStart, stayEnd, legalEnd, type, losDays
from (
  select
    custNum, legalStart, legalEnd, type,
    first_value(stayStart)
      over (partition by gg order by stayStart) as stayStart,
    first_value(stayEnd)
      over (partition by gg order by stayEnd) as stayEnd,
    first_value(losDays)
      over (partition by gg order by stayEnd) as losDays,
    sum(losDays)
      over (partition by gg order by stayStart) as accLosDays
  from (
    <<<<inner query>>>>
  where
    type=1
) zzz
where
  accLosDays >= 8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little messy in MySQL, which lacks support for analytic functions, but it can be done using variables, as follows (assuming your table is named "theTable"):

```
select custNum, legalStart, legalEnd, stayStart, stayEnd, type, losDays from (
  select
    @custNum as custNum,
    @legalStart as legalStart,
    @legalEnd as legalEnd,
    @stayStart as stayStart,
    @stayEnd as stayEnd,
    @type as type,
    @losDays as losDays,
    @newGroup :=
      (@custNum != custNum
        or @legalStart != legalStart
        or @legalEnd != legalEnd
        or @type != type)
      as newGroup,
    @aggLosDays as groupAggLosDays,
    @aggLosDays :=
        case when @newGroup
        then losDays
        else @aggLosDays + losDays end as __________,
    case when @newGroup then @losDays := losDays else null end as _,
    @custNum :=
        case when @custNum != custNum
        then custNum else @custNum end as ___,
    @legalStart :=
        case when @legalStart != legalStart
        then legalStart else @legalStart end as ____,
    @legalEnd :=
        case when @legalEnd != legalEnd
        then legalEnd else @legalEnd end as _____,
    @type :=
        case when @type != type
        then type else @type end as ______,
    @stayStart :=
        case when @newGroup
        then stayStart else @stayStart end as _______,
    @stayEnd :=
        case when @newGroup
        then stayEnd else @stayEnd end as ________
  from
    (
      (
        select
            custNum, legalStart, legalEnd, stayStart, stayEnd,
            type, datediff(stayEnd,stayStart) as losDays
        from theTable
        order by custNum, legalStart, legalEnd, stayStart, type
      ) union all (
          select -1, date('0000-00-00'), date('0000-00-00'),
              date('0000-00-00'), date('0000-00-00'), -1, null
      )
    ) tt
    join (select @aggLosDays := -1) z1
    join (select @custNum := -1) z2
    join (select @legalStart := date('0000-00-00')) z3
    join (select @legalEnd := date('0000-00-00')) z4
    join (select @stayStart := date('0000-00-00')) z5
    join (select @staylEnd := date('0000-00-00')) z6
    join (select @type := -1) z7
    join (select @losDays := null) z8
  order by
    custNum,
    legalStart,
    legalEnd,
    stayStart,
    stayEnd,
    type,
    losDays
) z
where
  newGroup
  and type=1
  and groupAggLosDays >= 8
;
```

This query uses variables to compute running totals across groups with the same customer, legal date range and type. The tricky part is that each row returned from the inner query does not actually contain any data from the current "theTable" row, but instead the contents of variables which represent roll-up date from previous rows in the same group. The @newGroup variable is set TRUE when the customer, legal date range or type has changed, indicating the start of a new group. The outer query's where clause will select a row from the inner query if it is flagged as a new group, has type=1 and has an aggregate number of days >= 8.

A "stub" row is appended to the "theTable" rows queried to trigger processing for the final group.

MySQL isn't my primary RDBMS, so I'm sure this could be made cleaner.

Comment: Thank you Mark.  A few questions.  What is this?   :=  Management Studio errors out on it and I can't find it searching for MySQL commands on the web.  MSSMS  also tells me there is no function named "date", so is that DATEADD? or something else?

Comment: My mistake, I misread what you wrote above as MySQL and not SQL Server.